# How can I get the current week using Python?

Tags: python, datetime, calendar

Using Python...

How can I get a list of the days in a specific week?

Something like...

```
{
'1' : ['01/03/2010','01/04/2010','01/05/2010','01/06/2010','01/07/2010','01/08/2010','01/09/2010'],  
'2' : ['01/10/2010','01/11/2010','01/12/2010','01/13/2010','01/14/2010','01/15/2010','01/16/2010'] 
}
```

The key of the dictionary in this example would be the week number.

Comment: Loop over every day, ask what day of the week it is - append to the right list.

Comment: See also very similar question from same person: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003870/how-can-i-select-all-of-the-sundays-for-a-year-using-python

Comment: It would be helpful to know what you want the dictionary for.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Beware! If you want to define YOUR OWN week numbers, you could use the generator expression provided [in your first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003870/how-can-i-select-all-of-the-sundays-for-a-year-using-python) which, by the way, got an awesome answer). If you want to follow the ISO convention for week numbers, you need to be careful:

> the first calendar week of a year is
>   that one which includes the first
>   Thursday of that year and [...] the
>   last calendar week of a calendar year
>   is the week immediately preceding the
>   first calendar week of the next
>   calendar year.

So, for instance, **January 1st and 2nd in 2010 were NOT week one of 2010**, but week 53 of 2009.

Python offers a module for finding the week number using the ISO calendar:

Example code:

```
h[1] >>> import datetime
h[1] >>> Jan1st = datetime.date(2010,1,1)
h[1] >>> Year,WeekNum,DOW = Jan1st.isocalendar() # DOW = day of week
h[1] >>> print Year,WeekNum,DOW
2009 53 5
```

Notice, again, how January 1st 2010 corresponds to week 53 of 2009.

Using the generator provided in the previous answer:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta


def allsundays(year):
    """This code was provided in the previous answer! It's not mine!"""
    d = date(year, 1, 1)                    # January 1st                                                          
    d += timedelta(days = 6 - d.weekday())  # First Sunday                                                         
    while d.year == year:
        yield d
        d += timedelta(days = 7)

Dict = {}
for wn,d in enumerate(allsundays(2010)):
    # This is my only contribution!
    Dict[wn+1] = [(d + timedelta(days=k)).isoformat() for k in range(0,7) ]

print Dict
```

Dict contains the dictionary you request.

Answer (score 8):

How do you identify weeks?  Here I'm identifying by a day in that week, using a function which gets the Sunday in that week (what you used in your example), and then returns it plus the next 6 days.

```
import datetime

one_day = datetime.timedelta(days=1)

def get_week(date):
  """Return the full week (Sunday first) of the week containing the given date.

  'date' may be a datetime or date instance (the same type is returned).
  """
  day_idx = (date.weekday() + 1) % 7  # turn sunday into 0, monday into 1, etc.
  sunday = date - datetime.timedelta(days=day_idx)
  date = sunday
  for n in xrange(7):
    yield date
    date += one_day

print list(get_week(datetime.datetime.now().date()))
# [datetime.date(2010, 1, 3), datetime.date(2010, 1, 4),
#  datetime.date(2010, 1, 5), datetime.date(2010, 1, 6),
#  datetime.date(2010, 1, 7), datetime.date(2010, 1, 8),
#  datetime.date(2010, 1, 9)]
print [d.isoformat() for d in get_week(datetime.datetime.now().date())]
# ['2010-01-03', '2010-01-04', '2010-01-05', '2010-01-06', '2010-01-07',
#  '2010-01-08', '2010-01-09']
```

Comment: i like this answer best coz it best fits my requirement. I want to know that for a given ( current date ) what is the beginning of the week and end. It may have been solved in 2010. Is it out of context to vote up.

Comment: It is the best solution when you need the sunday to be the first day of a week, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
current_week = datetime.datetime.now().isocalendar()[1]
```

Comment: This only gets the "week number" and does not address OP's requirements.

Answer (score 2):

There is a 3 lines method I developed after read that question:

```
from datetime import timedelta

def get_week_dates(base_date, start_day, end_day=None):
    """
    Return entire week of dates based on given date limited by start_day and end_day.
    If end_day is None, return only start_day.

    >>> from datetime import date
    >>> get_week_dates(date(2015,1,16), 3, 5)
    [datetime.date(2015, 1, 14), datetime.date(2015, 1, 15), datetime.date(2015, 1, 16)]

    >>> get_week_dates(date(2015,1,15), 2, 5)
    [datetime.date(2015, 1, 13), datetime.date(2015, 1, 14), datetime.date(2015, 1, 15), datetime.date(2015, 1, 16)]
    """
    monday = base_date - timedelta(days=base_date.isoweekday() - 1)
    week_dates = [monday + timedelta(days=i) for i in range(7)]
    return week_dates[start_day - 1:end_day or start_day]
```

Use `get_week_dates(date.today(), 1, 7)` to get current week dates.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the datetime module. You can specify the format and everything. Here's the link: http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html

Look into datetime.datetime( params ) and datetime.timedelta( params ). Hope it all goes well ;-)

Example:

```
import datetime

numweeks = 5
start_date = datetime.datetime(year=2010,month=1,day=4)    

weeks = {}

offset = datetime.timedelta(days=0)
for week in range(numweeks):
   this_week = []
   for day in range(7):
        date = start_date + offset
        date = date.strftime( some_format_string )
        this_week.append( date )
        offset += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
   weeks[week] = this_week
```

Comment: I'm aware of the datetime module. I hadn't found a nice/clean/good way to do this. Hoping someone would have already faced this issue or have some specific insight.

Comment: in general, dealing with date/time is never clean :(

Comment: Posted an example (untested). I hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code:

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()

now_day_1 = now - datetime.timedelta(days=now.weekday())

dates = {}

for n_week in range(3):
    dates[n_week] = [(now_day_1 + datetime.timedelta(days=d+n_week*7)).strftime("%m/%d/%Y") for d in range(7)]

print dates
```

prints:

```
{
 0: ['01/04/2010', '01/05/2010', '01/06/2010', '01/07/2010', '01/08/2010', '01/09/2010', '01/10/2010'], 
 1: ['01/11/2010', '01/12/2010', '01/13/2010', '01/14/2010', '01/15/2010', '01/16/2010', '01/17/2010'], 
 2: ['01/18/2010', '01/19/2010', '01/20/2010', '01/21/2010', '01/22/2010', '01/23/2010', '01/24/2010']
}
```

Comment: He is using Sunday as the first day in the week.

Answer (score 1):

If you're OK with the ISO standard:

```
>>> import collections
>>> dd = collections.defaultdict(list)
>>> jan1 = datetime.date(2010, 1, 1)
>>> oneday = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
>>> allyear = [jan1 + k*oneday for k in range(365 + 6)]
>>> for d in allyear:
...   y, w, wd = d.isocalendar()
...   if y == 2010: dd[w].append(d.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))
...
```

This produces slightly different results than the ones you're looking for (by ISO standard, weeks begin on Monday, not Sunday...), e.g.:

```
>>> dd[1]
['01/04/2010', '01/05/2010', '01/06/2010', '01/07/01/2010', '01/08/2010', '01/09/2010', '01/10/2010']
```

but you could tweak this by simulating an appropriate "off by one" error!-)

The [calendar](http://docs.python.org/library/calendar.html) modules let you set any weekday as "first day of week", but offers no simple way to get all weeks (without duplications when a week is split between two months), so I think that working directly off [datetime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#module-datetime) is probably a better idea.