# How can I select all of the Sundays for a year using Python?

Tags: python, datetime, calendar

Using Python...

How can I select all of the Sundays (or any day for that matter) in a year?

```
[ '01/03/2010','01/10/2010','01/17/2010','01/24/2010', ...]
```

These dates represent the Sundays for 2010. This could also apply to any day of the week I suppose.

Comment: Find the first Sunday and constantly add 7? Until you hit the limit of days for that month, then start from 0 ...

Comment: See also very similar question from same person: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003841/how-can-i-get-the-current-week-using-python

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can use `date` from the [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) module to find the first Sunday in a year and then keep adding seven days, generating new Sundays:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

def allsundays(year):
   d = date(year, 1, 1)                    # January 1st
   d += timedelta(days = 6 - d.weekday())  # First Sunday
   while d.year == year:
      yield d
      d += timedelta(days = 7)

for d in allsundays(2010):
   print(d)
```

Comment: Hey, I know its too late, but how to adjust the code for fetching saturdays

Comment: @sjpatel: You need to change the offset calculation to start with the first saturday instead of sunday. This could be done with `timedelta(days = (5 - d.weekday() + 7) % 7)`. Or, more explicitly `timedelta(days = (5 - d.weekday() if d.weekday() <= 5 else 7 + 5 - d.weekday()))`

Comment: It will lost the day where sunday is 1st.Use "today + datetime.timedelta(days=-today.weekday(), weeks=1)" will better.

Comment: @thouger pretty sure the original code works. January 1, 2012 is a Sunday. If you plug 2012 into the function it returns 2012-01-01 as the first entry.

Answer (score 31):

Pandas has great functionality for this purpose with its [`date_range()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html) function.

The result is a pandas `DatetimeIndex`, but can be converted to a list easily.

```
import pandas as pd

def allsundays(year):
    return pd.date_range(start=str(year), end=str(year+1), 
                         freq='W-SUN').strftime('%m/%d/%Y').tolist()

allsundays(2017)[:5]  # First 5 Sundays of 2017
# ['01/01/2017', '01/08/2017', '01/15/2017', '01/22/2017', '01/29/2017']
```

Answer (score 15):

Using the [dateutil module](http://labix.org/python-dateutil), you could generate the list this way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import dateutil.relativedelta as relativedelta
import dateutil.rrule as rrule
import datetime
year=2010
before=datetime.datetime(year,1,1)
after=datetime.datetime(year,12,31)
rr = rrule.rrule(rrule.WEEKLY,byweekday=relativedelta.SU,dtstart=before)
print rr.between(before,after,inc=True)
```

Although finding all Sundays is not too hard to do without dateutil, the module is handy especially if you have more complicated or varied date calculations.

If you are using Debian/Ubuntu, dateutil is provided by the python-dateutil package.

Comment: Shouldn't you replace before with after?

Answer (score 10):

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
from typing import List

def find_sundays_between(start: date, end: date) -> List[date]:
    total_days: int = (end - start).days + 1
    sunday: int = 6
    all_days = [start + timedelta(days=day) for day in range(total_days)]
    return [day for day in all_days if day.weekday() is sunday]


date_start: date = date(2018, 1, 1)
date_end: date = date(2018, 12, 31)
sundays = find_sundays_between(date_start, date_end)
```

Answer (score 7):

If looking for a **more general approach** (ie not only Sundays), we can build on [sth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/56338/sth)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2003906/8565438):

```
def weeknum(dayname):
    if dayname == 'Monday':   return 0
    if dayname == 'Tuesday':  return 1
    if dayname == 'Wednesday':return 2
    if dayname == 'Thursday': return 3
    if dayname == 'Friday':   return 4
    if dayname == 'Saturday': return 5
    if dayname == 'Sunday':   return 6
```

This will translate the name of the day into an `int`.

Then do:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
def alldays(year, whichDayYouWant):
    d = date(year, 1, 1)
    d += timedelta(days = (weeknum(whichDayYouWant) - d.weekday()) % 7)
    while d.year == year:
        yield d
        d += timedelta(days = 7)

for d in alldays(2020,'Sunday'):
    print(d)
```

Note the presence of `% 7` in `alldays()`. This outputs:

```
2020-01-05
2020-01-12
2020-01-19
2020-01-26
2020-02-02
2020-02-09
2020-02-16
...
```

Can also do:

```
for d in alldays(2020,'Friday'):
    print(d)
```

which will give you:

```
2020-01-03
2020-01-10
2020-01-17
2020-01-24
2020-01-31
2020-02-07
2020-02-14
...
```

Answer (score 6):

You can iterate over a calendar for that year.
The below should return all Tuesdays and Thursdays for a given year.

```
# Returns all Tuesdays and Thursdays of a given year
from datetime import date
import calendar

year = 2016
c = calendar.TextCalendar(calendar.SUNDAY)
for m in range(1,13):
    for i in c.itermonthdays(year,m):
        if i != 0:                                      #calendar constructs months with leading zeros (days belongng to the previous month)
            day = date(year,m,i)
            if day.weekday() == 1 or day.weekday() == 3: #if its Tuesday or Thursday
                print "%s-%s-%s" % (year,m,i)
```

Comment: Nice answer! For strangers I want to notice, just add brackets to the print expression and this code will run by Python 3

Answer (score 3):

```
import time
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

first_date = '2021-01-01'
final_date = '2021-12-31'
first_date = datetime.strptime(first_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
last_date = datetime.strptime(final_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
week_day = 'Sunday'
dates = [first_date + timedelta(days=x) for x in range((last_date - first_date).days + 1) if (first_date + timedelta(days=x)).weekday() == time.strptime(week_day, '%A').tm_wday]
```

It will return all Sunday date of given date range.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a complete generator function that builds on the solution from @sth. It includes the crucial fix that was mentioned in his solution's comments.

You can specify the day of week (using Python's indexing with 0=Monday to 6=Sunday), the starting date, and the number of weeks to enumerate.

```
def get_all_dates_of_day_of_week_in_year(day_of_week, start_year, start_month, 
                                         start_day, max_weeks=None):
    '''
    Generator function to enumerate all calendar dates for a specific day
    of the week during one year. For example, all Wednesdays in 2018 are:
    1/3/2018, 1/10/2018, 1/17/2018, 1/24/2018, 1/31/2018, 2/7/2018, etc.

    Parameters:
    ----------
    day_of_week : int
        The day_of_week should be one of these values: 0=Monday, 1=Tuesday, 
        2=Wednesday, 3=Thursday, 4=Friday, 5=Saturday, 6=Sunday.
    start_year : int
    start_month : int
    start_day : int
        The starting date from which to list out all the dates
    max_weeks : int or None
        If None, then list out all dates for the rest of the year.
        Otherwise, end the list after max_weeks number of weeks.
    '''

    if day_of_week < 0 or day_of_week > 6:
        raise ValueError('day_of_week should be in [0, 6]')

    date_iter = date(start_year, start_month, start_day)

    # First desired day_of_week
    date_iter += timedelta(days=(day_of_week - date_iter.weekday() + 7) % 7) 
    week = 1
    while date_iter.year == start_year:
        yield date_iter
        date_iter += timedelta(days=7)
        if max_weeks is not None:
            week += 1
            if week > max_weeks:
                break
```

Example usage to get all Wednesdays starting on January 1, 2018, for 10 weeks.

```
import calendar
day_of_week = 2
max_weeks = 10
for d in get_all_dates_of_day_of_week_in_year (day_of_week, 2018, 1, 1, max_weeks):
    print "%s, %d/%d/%d" % (calendar.day_name[d.weekday()], d.year, d.month, d.day)
```

The above code produces:

```
Wednesday, 2018/1/3
Wednesday, 2018/1/10
Wednesday, 2018/1/17
Wednesday, 2018/1/24
Wednesday, 2018/1/31
Wednesday, 2018/2/7
Wednesday, 2018/2/14
Wednesday, 2018/2/21
Wednesday, 2018/2/28
Wednesday, 2018/3/7
```

Answer (score 1):

according to @sth answer I like to give you an alternative without a function

```
from datetime import date, timedelta,datetime

sunndays = list()

year_var = datetime.now() #get current date
year_var = year_var.year  #get only the year

d = date(year_var, 1, 1)  #get the 01.01 of the current year = 01.01.2020

#now we have to skip 4 days to get to sunday.
#d.weekday is wednesday so it has a value of 2
d += timedelta(days=6 - d.weekday()) # 01.01.2020 + 4 days (6-2=4)

sunndays.append(str(d.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))) #you need to catch the first sunday

#here you get every other sundays
while d.year == year_var:
    d += timedelta(days=7)
    sunndays.append(str(d.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')))

print(sunndays) # only for control
```

if you want every monday for example

```
#for 2021 the 01.01 is a friday the value is 4
#we need to skip 3 days 7-4 = 3
d += timedelta(days=7 - d.weekday())
```

Answer (score 0):

according to @[sth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/56338/sth) answer,it will lost the day when 1st is sunday.This will be better:

```
d = datetime.date(year, month-1, 28)
for _ in range(5):
    d = d + datetime.timedelta(days=-d.weekday(), weeks=1)
    if d.month!=month:
        break
    date.append(d)
```