# Get last friday of each month in python

Tags: python, datetime, calendar, python-datetime

I want last friday of each month for upcoming three months.

```
Friday_date = datetime.date.today()

    while Friday_date.weekday() != 4:
        Friday_date += datetime.timedelta(1)
```

This gives me the nearest friday. I want to make sure this is the last friday of this month so that i can add 28 days to get next friday.

Comment: Get first day of next month, then subtract one. Then check the weekday of such date, and you can easily calculate the offset.

Comment: And with this answer you can find all Fridays in a year: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003870/how-can-i-select-all-of-the-sundays-for-a-year-using-python

Comment: I dont want all fridays.. checked..

Comment: I want next 3-4 months last fridays..

Comment: Do you know how you can calculate the last Friday of *any given month*? Then it shouldn't be hard to use that to calculate the next 3…

Comment: yeah thats what im searching

Comment: note: adding 28 won't always work because months have different number of days...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use the module [`dateutil`](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/):

```
>>> from dateutil.relativedelta import FR, relativedelta
>>> datetime.date.today()+relativedelta(day=31, weekday=FR(-1))
datetime.date(2021, 6, 25)
```

Don't assume you can get the last Friday of subsequent months just by adding 28 days. It won't always work. Adding 28 days to the last Friday of February 2024 gives you this:

```
>>> datetime.date(2024,2,1)+relativedelta(day=31, weekday=FR(-1), days=28)
datetime.date(2024, 3, 22)
```

but the last Friday of that month is 29 March. Let `dateutil` do that correctly for you:

```
>>> datetime.date(2024,2,1)+relativedelta(day=31, weekday=FR(-1), months=1)
datetime.date(2024, 3, 29)
```

Comment: This is giving the last friday of the current month and i can add 28 easily to get upcoming months.

Comment: Be careful of just adding 28 days. It won't always work. `datetime.date(2024,2,1)+relativedelta(day=31, weekday=FR(-1), weeks=4)` gives 22 March 2024 but the last Friday of that month is 29 March. But `datetime.date(2024,2,1)+relativedelta(day=31, weekday=FR(-1), months=1)` gives you the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

If needed with standard library only, here is with `calendar` and `datetime`:

```
import calendar
from datetime import date

today = date.today()
year, month = today.year, today.month

n_months = 4
friday = calendar.FRIDAY

for _ in range(n_months):
    # get last friday
    c = calendar.monthcalendar(year, month)
    day_number = c[-1][friday] or c[-2][friday]

    # display the found date
    print(date(year, month, day_number))

    # refine year and month
    if month < 12:
        month += 1
    else:
        month = 1
        year += 1
```

where the line `c[-1][friday] or c[-2][friday]` first checks the last week of the month: is Friday nonzero there? if so take it, else look at the week before where there *must* be a Friday.

This prints

```
2021-06-25
2021-07-30
2021-08-27
2021-09-24
```

Comment: This should be the **right** answer to original PO.

Answer (score 1):

This formula gets you the day of the last Friday of any given month:

```
import calendar

year = 2021
month = 6

last_day = calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]
last_weekday = calendar.weekday(year, month, last_day)
last_friday = last_day - ((7 - (4 - last_weekday)) % 7)
#                          ^    ^
#                          |    Friday
#                          days in a week
```

This is my first coffee, so this can probably be condensed a bit, but it illustrates the logic. `last_day` is the last calendar day (30 for June), `last_weekday` is what weekday it is (`2` for Wednesday), and based on that we simply calculate how many days to subtract to land on the last Friday (`25`).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the last friday you can do this :

```
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta

today = date.today()
offset = (today.weekday() - 4) % 7
last_wednesday = today - timedelta(days=offset)
```

Comment: The OP want the last friday of the month, not the previous friday