# How to determine if the date is the last Thursday or first Thursday of the Current Month in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, calendar

I would like to print out "Last Thurs" if the date is the last Thursday of the month and "First Thurs" if the date is the first Thursday of the current month.

For example:

Date: **May 27, 2022**
Output: **Last Thurs**

Date: **May 5, 2022**
Output: **First Thurs**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the last thursday of the current month using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36975886/get-the-last-thursday-of-the-current-month-using-python)

Comment: So, what have you actually tried?

Comment: @user56700 more concise (imho): https://stackoverflow.com/a/68014702/10197418