# Calendar start and end of the week in Python

Tags: python

Given that first of January is a wednesday (or any other day of the week), I'd like to know the day of each Monday and Sunday of a calendar.

Taking into consideration leap years.

This is what I did:

```
leap = False 
    count = 0
    days_of_week = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
    start_week = {}
    # month and number of days in a month
    months = {"January": 31, "February": 28, "March": 31, "April": 30, "May": 31, "June": 30, "July": 31, "August": 31, "September": 30, "October": 31, "November": 30, "December": 31}
    
    for key, value in months.items():
        print(key, '->', value)
        start_week[key] = {"start": days_of_week[0], "end": days_of_week[-1]}
        print(start_week)
    
    if Y >= 2001 and Y <= 2100:
        if Y % 4 == 0:
            leap = True
        
        else:
            for w in days_of_week:
                print(f"{w} : {count}")
                count+=1
            
        print(leap)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I'd like to know the day of each Monday and Sunday of a calendar

Comment: See here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19216334/python-give-start-and-end-of-week-data-from-a-given-date

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48241484/6298712), specifically, which could easily be modified for both Sundays and Mondays.

Comment: @ddejohn Thanks, will try adapting it.

Comment: @AnaClaudia That isn't a question. What problems did you encounter while trying to solve this? What happens when you run your code? What do you want it to do instead? For some more tips on asking questions here, check out [ask].

Comment: @Code-Apprentice see ddejohn comment