# Days/dates in a given week

Tags: python, datetime, calendar, week-number, isodate

I'm trying to get a list with days in a given week.
I can get the year and week.

E.g.:

```
>>> year, week, dow = datetime.today().isocalendar()
>>> week
>>> 39
```

I'd like to get the 7 days in the week 39.  For this year, 2015, I would get

```
[21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]
```

As shown [here](http://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/index.html?country=18&year=)

**Note**

I've found lot's of questions asking for:

- [How to get number of week?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600775/how-to-get-week-number-in-python)
- [Current week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277002/how-to-get-all-datetime-instances-of-the-current-week-given-a-day)

This is not a duplicate, I don't need the last 7 days and I already have the current week number.

I need to get the 7 days in a given week, in this case, week 39. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difficulty with the `isocalendar` is that it's not really counting day-of-month. Therefore you have to translate back in order to get that. `strptime` can help:

```
year, week, dow = datetime.today().isocalendar()
result = [datetime.strptime(str(year) + "-" + str(week-1) + "-" + str(x), "%Y-%W-%w").day for x in range(1,7)]
```

What we are doing here is constructing a string that `striptime` can understand, starting with a week back (to account for counting from 0 versus 1) and starting at the start of the week (Monday, which is `1`) and constructing a datetime for each day going forward 7 days.

By playing with `week` between those two statements (adding or removing weeks to get to month breaks) we can see that it works:

```
>>> year, week, dow = datetime.today().isocalendar()
>>> result = [datetime.strptime(str(year) + "-" + str(week-1) + "-" + str(x), "%Y-%W-%w").day for x in range(1,7)]
>>> result
[21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26]
>>> year, week, dow = datetime.today().isocalendar()
>>> week = week + 1
>>> result = [datetime.strptime(str(year) + "-" + str(week-1) + "-" + str(x), "%Y-%W-%w").day for x in range(1,7)]
>>> result
[28, 29, 30, 1, 2, 3]
```

Now, to address the two very real concerns raised in comments we have to modify things a little bit:

```
year, week, dow = datetime.today().isocalendar()
week_start = datetime.strptime(str(year) + "-" + str(week-2) + "-0", "%Y-%W-%w")
result = [(week_start + timedelta(days=x)).day for x in range(0,7)]
```

This uses `timedelta` to increment. To make this work we have to back up across the week divide (hence the `-2` instead of `-1`). Then the for comprehension adds an increasingly large time delta as we iterate through the week:

```
>>> year, week, dow = datetime.today().isocalendar()
>>> week_start = datetime.strptime(str(year) + "-" + str(week-2) + "-0", "%Y-%W-%w")
>>> result = [(week_start + timedelta(days=x)).day for x in range(0,7)]
>>> result
[20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26]
>>> year, week, dow = datetime.today().isocalendar()
>>> week = week + 1
>>> week_start = datetime.strptime(str(year) + "-" + str(week-2) + "-0", "%Y-%W-%w")
>>> result = [(week_start + timedelta(days=x)).day for x in range(0,7)]
>>> result
[27, 28, 29, 30, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: It's returning 6 days. I know isocalendar consider monday as 1, but I have been working with weekday from datetime which consider Monday as 0. How can this fit to work with Monday 0 and Sunday 6?

Comment: Check the update! See if that addresses your concern.

Comment: It's pretty close dude, I work with Monday as 0 I will try to get a list wirh dates from Monday to Sunday. I can see you are returning from Sunday to Saturday. In the link I provided [this](http://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/index.html?country=18&year=) week are counted from mon to sun, currently in week 39 as in my answer, is that possible?

Comment: I'm sure it's just a matter of adjusting the 'dow' offset. To effectively bridge from where you're using it to the code snippets above, you'd need to provide an example of what your expected inputs and outputs are.

Comment: Now I will try to adjust it to get not only de date number, but the full date.

Answer (score 1):

of course can be improved, but works it seems....

```
def days_of_the_current_numbered_week():

    import datetime
    import  calendar

     # dictionary of days of the week
    days = {   0 :  "Sunday",
            1 : "Monday",
            2 : "Tuesday",
            3 : "Wednesday",
            4 : "Thursday",
            5 : "Friday",
            6 : "Saturday",
            7 : "Sunday" }


    allYearDates = []
    w_days_numbers = []

    # today
    now = datetime.datetime.now()

    # get current values for year, mon, day
    year = int(now.year)
    mon = int(now.month)
    day = int(now.day)

    # get this week number
    # thisWeekN = datetime.date(year, mon, day).isocalendar()[1]

    thisWeekN = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isocalendar()[1]

    # get Calendar obect
    c = calendar.Calendar()

    # get all the days for this year in a list
    for i in range(1, 13):
        for d in c.itermonthdays2(year, i):
            allYearDates.append(d)
    # in the first seven days could be 0's as days, to continue week #'s
    # these tuples need to be removed to produce accurate mapping between
    # weeks and 7 days chunks
    first_seven = allYearDates[:7]
    no_zeros =  [ d for d in first_seven if  d[0] != 0]

    allYearDates = no_zeros + allYearDates[8:]
    # divid all days of year list into one week chuncks
    lt7 = listChunks(allYearDates,7)

    # get days for this week number
    thisWeekDays = lt7[thisWeekN]

    # remove right part of the days tuple
    sevenDaysL = [x for x,y in  thisWeekDays]

    # get week day numbers  1-7 for this week
    for d in sevenDaysL:
        w_days_numbers.append(datetime.date(year, mon, d).isocalendar()[2])

    # zip week day numbers with the dates
    zl = zip(sevenDaysL, w_days_numbers)

    # month number prefix
    if thisWeekN == 1:
        prefix = 'st'
    elif thisWeekN == 2:
        prefix = 'nd'
    elif thisWeekN == 3:
        prefix = 'rd'
    else:
        prefix= "th"

    # print heading
    print("\n 7 days of this {}{} week: of the year {}"
          .format(thisWeekN,prefix, year))
    print("-------------------------------------------")

    # print results
    for el in  list(zl):
        if el[0] == day:
            print("* {} *  {}".format(el[0],days[el[1]]))
        else:
            print("  {}    {}".format(el[0],days[el[1]]))

    mytime= datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M")
    print("================")
    print(mytime)
```

days_of_the_current_numbered_week()

**OUTPUT**

7 days of this 39th week: of the year 2015

17    Thursday

18    Friday

19    Saturday

20    Sunday

21    Monday

22   Tuesday

23    Wednesday

Comment: Bice approach, I will give it a try. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First, find the day of the week on which the year begins.  This is easy to find on the internet.  This gives you the offset of week 1 in the year.

Notice that the week will let you compute the day of the year, in the range 1-365.  Week 01 starts on day 1; week 02 starts on day 8, etc.

start_day = 1 + (week-1) * 7 - offset

First, find the day of the week on which the year begins.  This is easy to find on the internet.  This gives you the offset of week 1 in the year.

now that you have the start day, you can easily find the day of the month.  It's a little tedious to subtract the days in each month until you get into range of the given month, but it's straightforward.

Does this get you going?  I've done this in English description, since you haven't given us any code to debug.

Comment: Sometimes 1st Jan is not in the first week as you can see [here](http://www.epochconverter.com/date-and-time/weeknumbers-by-year.php?year=2010)

Comment: Right -- hence computing the offset.