# Converting python date to week

Tags: python, date

```
 datetime.date(2010, 1, 1).isocalendar()[1]
```

gives week number 53 since 1st Jan 2010 was in a week which started in 2009. However, I would like to start Jan 1, 2010 as week 1. Is there any option in datetime isocalendar to do this?

If I follow the solution at [How can I get the current week using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003841/how-can-i-get-the-current-week-using-python), I get 53 as result

Comment: No, just subtract 52.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get the current week using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003841/how-can-i-get-the-current-week-using-python)

Comment: Not a duplicate, the solution there will give 53 as result and not 1 which is what I want

Comment: That's because it *is the 53rd week*. This is the standard. There simply isn't a way to do this the way you want to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compute the number of days since the first of the year, integer-divide by 7 and add 1:

```
>>> import datetime as DT
>>> (DT.date(2010,1,1)-DT.date(2010,1,1)).days // 7 + 1
1
```

This notion of week number is very different from the [ISO week definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#Calculating_the_week_number_of_a_given_date), so you aren't going to find an option to do this in `isocalendar`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be getting data in total weeks since a point, you can mod that number by the number of weeks in a year (52) to get the remainder (ie, how many weeks into the year you are):

```
>>> 53 % 52
>>> 1
>>> 925 % 52
>>> 41
```